# Divides dates in day, month, week Django

Tags: python, django, date, charts, django-queryset

I need generate a chart of orders closed by day and month.
Generate average, total sum, etc.
But i need to split its data by period between two dates.
start date = '01/01/2015'
end_date = '01/04/2015'
I need generate the data: so

Exemple:

2015/01/01
Total sum: 100, average: 10

2015/02/01
Total sum: 500, average:50

2015/03/01
Total sum: 40, average:2

2015/04/01
Total sum: 40, average:2

But in Django, my queryset return a total between two dates

```
filter_params = self.request.GET
context['orders_confirmed'] = Bid.objects.filter(date_confirmed__gte=filter_params.get('summary_date'))
context['orders_confirmed'] = context['orders_confirmed'].filter(date_confirmed__lte=filter_params.get('final_summary_date'))
```

it shows me only a total, exemple 1500, how I divide its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)** for time intervals.

e.g.-
first_time = datetime.now() or in your case first_time = filter_params.get('summary_date')

second_time = first_time + timedelta(days=30)

. . .

end_time = filter_params.get('finally_summary_date')

run your second filter query on desired time intervals.